# How to get the home directory from a variable in expect?

Tags: expect

I'd like to set the home directory as a variable.

How can I do that?

This is my code:

```
set fp [open "$HOME/temp.sh" r]
set data [read $fp]
close $fp
set ::logfile [open "$HOME/log.sh" a]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Expect is an extension of Tcl, you use Tcl's `env` array:

```
set fp [open "$::env(HOME)/temp.sh" r]
set data [read $fp]
close $fp
set ::logfile [open "$::env(HOME)/log.sh" a]
```

See http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/tclvars.htm and [the Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html).